# Changing Environment Variable for Dart/Flutter Installation not working correctly

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart

I am currently trying to install Dart/Flutter on my PC but I am running into some problems. I downloaded the Dart SDK folder and saved it in my C folder in a folder I named dart. I then went into the bin folder which is within my dark-sdk folder and copied the file location. I then went to add it to my path for environment variables which is what I saw a lot of people doing in tutorials. After doing all that, I went to my CMD prompt and typed in the command dart --version which gave me an error saying that the command wasn't recognized. I am stuck and don't know what to do. I provided screenshots here also to help clarify my problem. [image]

[image]

Comment: You may need to open a new console window, I am not sure the paths you set in that window work retroactively.

Comment: It works after opening a new console window thank you so much!